# Why .apk file is not downloading to some mobile devices?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I have uploaded an apk file to my web page and by typing a URL like www.example.com/mobile/example.apk in mobile browser, it is downloading to some mobile but in some mobile the "Unsuccessful Download" message is displayed.

It is successfully downloaded to HTC desire x and Samsung Galaxy Grand duos but not for others, like Samsung Galaxy Y, Samsung S3 etc.

Please help to solve this issue as I don't know whether it is .apk uploading problem on webpage, which means on server side, or in my android code. Does android:installLocation="auto" make in difference in this?

Comment: The problem's with downloading the file, not with the app. It might because of some bug or issue with the downloader or internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give .apk file directly to user it will occur error for lower end devices, Give apk file in a compressed .zip file. It will avoid these type of errors. It is one the secure way to deliver data.